# In golang How to split a URL and encode back to URL from decoded components. Any packages?

Tags: url, go

In golang How to split a URL and encode back to URL from decoded components. Any packages that do the job?

[net/url](http://golang.org/pkg/net/url/) helps only in decoding the URL. I want to modify the `HOST` and `PORT` and recreate the URL. My problem originates from the case where I receive `IPV6:port` without square brackets. Let us say  I get `IPV6:port` in the format as:

```
aaa:abbb:cccc:dddd:0000:0000:00aa:bbbb:8080/static/silly.html
```

I want to reconstruct the URL with brackets arround IPV6 address.

Comment: Valid IPv6 in URLs do have square brackets, with or without the port number. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Literal_IPv6_addresses_in_network_resource_identifiers

Comment: Yes fiorix, i am aware, hence was my question as the legacy product my program interacts with gives me URL without square brackets.

Answer (score 4):

I think that would not be possible. For instance, if you get:

```
2001:db8::1:80
```

How could you tell if the IP address is

```
2001:db8::1
```

Or:

```
2001:db8::1:80
```

That is the reason why [RFC 5952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5952#section-6) recommands to use brackets (or some other characters) to distinguish the IP address from the port number.

Consequently, if possible, I recommand you to ignore this ambiguous formatting.

---

**UPDATE**

Actually, you can do what you want if you are sure to be able to distinguish the two parts, which is when you can count exatcly 8 occurences of the character `:`.

```
if strings.Count(url, ":") == 8 {
    split := strings.Split(url, ":")
    url = "[" + strings.Join(split[:8], ":") + "]:" + split[8]
}
```

But this is probably not the best idea to process this kind of url formatting anyway...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard `net` package to help in the process [Playground][[http://play.golang.org/p/wz0g7rgdU4]](http://play.golang.org/p/wz0g7rgdU4%5d)

I use the `net.ParseIP` and `net.JoinHostPort`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "strings"
)

func splitLastColumn(host string) (string, string, string) {
    idx := strings.Index(host, "/")
    col_idx := strings.LastIndex(host[:idx], ":")
    return host[:col_idx], host[col_idx+1 : idx], host[idx:]
}

func main() {
    ipstr := "aaa:abbb:cccc:dddd:0000:0000:00aa:bbbb:8080/static/silly.html"

    host, port, path := splitLastColumn(ipstr)
    ip := net.ParseIP(host)
    if ip == nil {
      fmt.Println("invalid addr ")
    }
    fmt.Println(ip, host, port, path)
    fmt.Println(net.JoinHostPort(host, port))
}
```